# External Variables not being recognized correctly

Tags: bash

i have got this problem: When i put my variables into an external "configstyle" file and import the file with `. /var/scripts/siDiagConfig.sh` the variables don´t work properly...
Like i have a variable called `MTU=1500` and when i echo it, it prints "1500", which is correct. But when I want to use the variable within a grep command like `somethingawesome | grep ${MTU} -c` the variable is not recognized properly. In this example, the console prints 0, instead of 2... When i reassign the variable with `MTU=1500`, the code works without any problems....
Any idea, what i could have missed?

Is there any other way, i could put my variables in an external file?

my siDiagConfig.sh File:

```
#!/bin/bash
....
export MTU=1500
....
```

edit (Solution):

I remembered, that i created the file on my windows system. I just copied the code in the siDiagConfig.sh, created a new file on the unix system, and pasted the code there. Now it works without any problems =)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try declaring them like `export MTU=1500` in that external file?

Comment: Now i did ;) Did not work, though :(

Comment: can you print the output when you use set -vx before the grep line?

Comment: my command is: `xe pif-list device=eth$1 params=MTU | grep $MTU -c` where do i put the -vx for your purpose?

Comment: Show us the siDiagConfig.sh. Maybe you fall victim to the "variables assigned in subshells are not visible outside" problem.

Comment: Which platform are you on — Linux or something else?  Which version of Bash are you using (`bash --version`)?  Given that your `grep ${MTU} -c` works at all, you're probably on a system with the GNU C library, because everywhere else requires options such as `-c` to precede non-option arguments such as `${MTU}`.

Comment: Write: `set -vx; xe pif-list device=eth$1 params=MTU | grep $MTU -c; set +vx`.

Comment: I am scripting this on a windows maschine, but execute on a XenServer (Linux).The `set -xv` showed: `+++ xe pif... bla +++ grep $´1500\r´ -c +++ set=vx`
I think that `\r` is something, that could cause the problem... Whatever that is or where it comes from...

Comment: And as is said, the variable is visible in my main.sh file. I can print it and so on...

Comment: Yes; that `\r` is the trouble.  It is a carriage return.  Convert DOS files to Unix files before executing them on Unix.

Comment: Ok, now i remembered, that i created the file on my windows system. I just copied the code in the siDiagConfig.sh, created a new file on the unix system, and pasted the code there. Not it works without any poroblems =) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[gigauser@gigabox : /scm/gigafolder/toratora/test_aks]

> cat conf.config ; echo -----; cat testfile.txt ; echo ------; cat mainfile.sh ; echo --------; ./mainfile.sh

export GIGA=giga

export fifa=FIFA

---

I'm GIGA

I like fifa

---

```
 #!/bin/bash

. conf.config

echo GIGA = $GIGA
echo fifa = $fifa

cat -n testfile.txt


echo
echo -- Now lets grep = $GIGA with case insensitive On
echo

echo -`grep -in "${GIGA}" testfile.txt`-; 
echo =`grep -ic  "${GIGA}" testfile.txt`=
echo
echo Now again but with case insensitive Off
echo -`grep -n "${GIGA}" testfile.txt`-;
echo =`grep -c  "${GIGA}" testfile.txt`=
```

---

GIGA = giga

fifa = FIFA
     1  I'm GIGA
     2  I like fifa


-- Now lets grep = giga with case insensitive On


-1:I'm GIGA-

=1=


Now again but with case insensitive Off

--

=0=

[gigauser@gigabox : /scm/gigafolder/toratora/test_aks]

>

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

Yes; that \r is the trouble. It is a carriage return. Convert DOS files to Unix files before executing them on Unix. – Jonathan Leffler

Ok, now i remembered, that i created the file on my windows system. I just copied the code in the siDiagConfig.sh, created a new file on the unix system, and pasted the code there. Not it works without any poroblems =) Thanks for the help! – Simons0n